# Run container in host, but with dedicated IP

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to start a container with docker-compose in the host network, so it can access other services running on the host, but I want to give it a dedicated IP. Can this be done? I tried with the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  my-service:
    image: my-image
    networks:
      host:
        ipv4_address: 172.0.58.1
```

When starting this `docker-compose.yml`, I get:

```
ERROR: Service "my-service" uses an undefined network "host"
```

Comment: You can't configure host networking at all; it basically disables all of the Docker networking stack.  It's also usually unnecessary.  Is there a specific problem you're running into with the standard Docker networking setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot networks key. Try like this:

```
services:
  my-service:
    image: my-image
    networks:
      host:
        ipv4_address: 172.0.58.1
networks:
 host:
  ipam:
   driver: default
   config:
   - subnet: 172.0.58.0/24
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `ipam` here? Does this refer to network host mode?

Comment: From documentation - "The corresponding network configuration in the top-level networks section must have an ipam block with subnet and gateway configurations covering each static address."
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#ipv4_address-ipv6_address

host mode is configured by "driver: default"

Comment: Got it! That should do it. Thank you very much!